# Rendering instance variables in the view -rails 3

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to figure out how to render the same view for each instance of my class when outputting to the view

heres my example

I have an app where you can record your own recipes and in an area called "my recipes" view all recipes entered. So far I can render the view for one instance in the style i want it presented

```
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <ul class="thumbnails">
    <li class="span4">
     <div class="thumbnail">
     <% @recipes.each do |r| %>
      <%= image_tag r.avatar.url(:medium)%>
      <h3 class="center"><a href="#"><%= r.dish_name %></a></h3>
      <p>Description of dish</p>
   </div>
  </li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>    
 </div>
</div>
```

In my controller I have this

```
  def my_recipes

 @recipes = current_user.recipes if current_user.recipes #show recipes if the user has  any recipes

 end
```

How do i get every instance to render in the same view, ie as i have specified above/ Sure this is simple but cannot figure this out tonight

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this more a case of getting the format correct in the view first?

E.g. if you want a thumbnail for each item in the collection.

```
<li class="span4">
 <div class="thumbnail">
 <% @recipes.each do |r| %>
  <%= image_tag r.avatar.url(:medium)%>
  <h3 class="center"><a href="#"><%= r.dish_name %></a></h3>
  <p>Description of dish</p>
```

Might look better if you do:

```
 <% @recipes.each do |r| %>
   <li class="span4">
     <div class="thumbnail">
       <%= image_tag r.avatar.url(:medium)%>
       <h3 class="center"><a href="#"><%= r.dish_name %></a></h3>
       <p>Description of dish</p>
     </div>
   </li>
  <% end %>
```

Means you get an 'li' element for each listed item in the collection.

Then perhaps after that, throw the html into a partial if required

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're talking about partials. See [this part](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials) of the view rendering guide. Specifically, section 3.4.5, 'Rendering Collections'. If you name your files in the manner Rails expects, this is probably as simple as `<%= render @recipes %>`.